# Get-ChildItem -Filter Array

Tags: powershell, filter

Situation:

1. `Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter *.dll` works for me
2. This works:

   ```
   $Path = "$env:windir\system32\*"
   $GuyArray = @("*.dll", "*.exe")

   Get-ChildItem $Path -Include $GuyArray
   ```
3. But I cannot get this working:

   ```
   $Path = "$env:windir\system32\*"
   $GuyArray = @("*.dll", "*.exe")

   Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter $GuyArray
   ```

Error message:

> Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Filter'. Specified method is not supported.

Questions:

1. Does this mean that `-Include` supports multiple values, but `-Filter` only allows one value?
2. If the above explaination is correct, is there a way I could have discovered this from `Get-Help gci`?

Comment: Should the item #3 be `Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter $GuyArray`?

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake, #3 should have been -Filter and not -Include

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does this mean that `-Include` supports multiple values, but `-Filter` only allows one value?

Yes.

> If the above explaination is correct, is there a way I could have discovered this from `Get-Help gci`?

Yes, but you do not get much information by `Get-Help gci -Parameter Filter`. But you still can see it is a string, not an array. As for the details, `Filter` is a provider-specific filter. `Get-Help gci` cannot tell you anything about implementation in a particular provider. In theory, `Get-Help FileSystem` (help about this provider) should have explained this.

P.S. Also note that this filter rather uses CMD wildcard rules than PowerShell wilcard rules.

Comment: Do parameters which accept arrays have square brackets after the word string?  -Include <string[]>.  Whereas those only accepting strings have -Filter <string>?

Answer (score 2):

Question 1:

Yes. `-Filter` accepts only `[string]` as input. `-Include` accepts `[String[]]`.

Question 2:

`Get-help get-childitem -parameter filter` gives

```
-Filter <string>
...explanation...
```

`Get-help get-childitem -parameter include` gives

```
-Include <string[]>
...explanation...
```

Comment: I appreciate your pointing out the significance of [Square brackets] within <string[]>

Answer (score 1):

Using `Get-Help`:

```
> get-help Get-ChildItem

NAME
    Get-ChildItem

SYNTAX
    Get-ChildItem [[-Path] <string[]>] [[-Filter] <string>] [-Exclude <string[]>] [-Force] [-Include <string[]>] [-Name] [-Recurse] [-UseTransaction] [<CommonParameters>]
```

The SYNTAX section includes the parameter types, from which you can see that `Filter` is a string, and `Path` an array.

Comment: Thank you, I see what to look for now.