# Powershell GCI include with arraylist

Tags: powershell

```
 $pdfs = @(gci $pioneerDest -Include $arrPDFName.Item(0), $arrPDFName.Item(0)  | foreach {write-output $_.name})
```

So I want to grab pdfs from a directory.  However I only want the pdfs that will be the arraylist `$arrPDFName`. I cannot find a way to do this.  Does anyone have any idea of using the powershell's collections with `Get-ChildItem`?

Comment: What does `$arrPDFName` look like?

Comment: It is essentially a list of strings.  so file1.pdf, file2.pdf, file3.pdf........

Comment: Just `gci $arrPDFName` then would do it assuming you were in the right folder. It would fail if one of the items does not exist. `gci $pdfs -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` would address that but you would not know what failed.

Comment: The files won't have the full paths though.  I am thinking that this will cry foul on not having the full path to each file

Comment: All of the files are already double checked and handled if not there so at this point in the script i won't need to worry about error handling

Comment: `gci $pioneerDest -include $arrPDFName -Recurse`. Include does not work well without recurse.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler I saw that. The only difference is that it would spit out what actually exists. Although the OP said they have already been scrubbed. Might just be a silly MVCE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming something simple for your list like a list of file names you were on the right track.

`-Include` accepts arrays so there is not need to break it out. Just use it explicitly. In practice `-include` and `-exclude` work only when `-Recurse` is used. You can find *a little* more information on that from [Get-ChildItem -Filter Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858901/get-childitem-filter-array). Technet is also a good resource for this: [`Get-ChildItem`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx)

```
$arrPDFName = "text.txt","test.csv"
$pioneerDest = "c:\temp"
$pdfs = Get-ChildItem $pioneerDest -include $arrPDFName -Recurse | Select-Object -Expand Name
```

I removed the `foreach-object` loop since you were just using that to return properties. That is what `Select-Object` is for. You might also consider swapping out `Name` for `FullName` to get the full path.

Comment: So had tried above before with the -Recurse that is what i was missing.  Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

Feed the list of names into gci through the pipeline, it will handle it.

```
$arrPDFName | gci
```

If they are actually full filenames *in the current directory*, and you know they all exist, that should be enough.

If they're not in the current directory, I'd be quite tempted to

```
$arrPDFName |% { "$pioneerDest\$_" } | gci
```

To loop over them and make them all full path names on the way into `gci`. Or `cd $pioneerDest` first.